# Only a small portion of my export page renders

Tags: admin, export, management

Has anyone had this problem before? Only a few options are showing.

[image: Export page]

Comment: I see similar thing happen every once in a while and it is usually caused by WP running out of memory. Could you check (e.g. with ftp) if there's an `error_log` in your WP directory with errors about `Allowed memory size of (some number) bytes exhausted..`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems to be saying that it can't load export.php. I have no idea how to sort that. Export.php is in the right place.

Comment: Could you add the full error to your question? (Do remove site name and such from paths if there's any) One thing that comes to my mind is, if you've recently updated WP then perhaps something went during the update, but this is just a wild guess. You could try updating the WP core again ( either clicking the reinstall button on Updates page or by transfering the files with ftp ) and see if that works.